# How join four tables using join query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have 4 tables

**answers**

```
id
qid (question id)
appid (applicant id)
answer (user answer 1/0)
```

**question**

```
id
jobid (job type id)
questiontext 
weight ( it could be 1/0)
```

**postnewjb**

```
id
jobid
jobtxt
```

**applicants**

```
id
jobid
name
email
```

I have to calculate the percentage of the answer of all the user for a specific `jobid` using following formula

for example user answered 3 questions

percentage each answer =  100/(total no of question for)

if user answered 1 for a question and the question weight is 1 then full percentage of the question should be added . and we should calculate total of all the %

```
 $jobid=Postnewjob::where('id',$jobid)->get();

 foreach($jobid as $job){
  $jobId=$job->jobid;
 }

 $apps=applicants::where('jobid','=',$jobId)->get();

 foreach($apps as $apo){
  $appid[]=$apo->id;
 }


 $score=answers::whereIn('appid',$appid)->where('jobid','=',$jobId)->get();

 $qid=array();
 foreach($score as $s){
  $qid[]=$s->qid;
 }
 $queid=questions::whereIn('id',$qid)->get();

 $calscore=100/(count($queid));
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort...

Comment: @AlexBlex im updating the query that i have written

Comment: To obtain a correct answer, please add a coherent example: table data sample => desired output.